# Elasticsearch Query for field with multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to write an Elasticsearch query that will return only documents that have multiple values in a given field? I don't care what those values are, only that a field has multiple, instead of 1.

I'd like the query to match:

```
{
  "color": ["red", "blue"]
},
{
  "color": ["green", "yellow", "orange"]
}
```

but not

```
{
  "color": "red"
}
```

Ideally, I'd prefer to avoid using scripts in my query; they are disabled on my cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a solution approach that works without using a script. But you have choice:

**Preparation: Index some sample documents**

```
POST my_index/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": 1}}
{"color": ["red", "blue"]}
{"index": {"_id": 2}}
{"color": ["green", "yellow", "orange"]}
{"index": {"_id": 3}}
{"color": ["grey"]}
```

**Option 1: Using a script at query time ("expensive")**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc.color.size() > 1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Option 2: Using a script at indexing time ("cheap")**

(preferred approach, as the script only gets executed once per document write)

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/set_number_of_colors
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "ctx.number_of_colors = ctx.color.size()"
      }
    }
  ]
}

POST my_index/_update_by_query?pipeline=set_number_of_colors

GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "number_of_colors": {"gt": 1}
    }
  }
}
```

You can also configure the pipeline as default pipeline for your index, so you don't need to change anything in your indexing application logic.

Comment: I wouldn't say that I'm "happy" with it, since I cannot use scripts in my cluster, but it does appear to be correct. :P